# Vertical Scrolling Not Working for Mobile - Touch

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I'm having an issue getting an div to allow mobile device to touch and vertical scroll. Scrolling works fine if you scroll your mouse wheel or use arrow keys. Just not touch. This has been tested on all device and in emulation.Please for the love of god help me lol it's been 3 days no luck. And I've done this in the past with no issues, I think I've gone full idiot, hahaha.

Below is an image of the scroll-able area, the colored borders yellow/black are to help you determine whats going on. This is for tablets and smaller.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/103696749012467712/491964310436970499/1.PNG

```
export const CategoriesBox = styled.div`
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 310px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  @media only screen and (max-width: ${breakpoints.tablet}) {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 310px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  & input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  & label {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 21px;
  }
`;

export const ScrollableBox = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
`;
```

I removed the webkit stuff and tried a few things some friends shown me. Below is the new styled component code. The ref image is still the same. Again, I can scroll it fine using scroll wheel or up/down arrows.

```
export const CategoriesBox = styled.div`
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 310px;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  @media only screen and (max-width: ${breakpoints.tablet}) {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 310px;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }

  & input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  & label {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 21px;
  }
`;

export const ScrollableBox = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 1.5px solid red;
`;
```

Comment: why do you have `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`?

Comment: I read online I need it for IOS support or some browser to give it a bouncy-ish effect when dragging on scroll instead of a dead stop when it hits the en of the div. Although I guess not because styled components takes care of all prefixes for me anyways correct?

I also added some new code tried to the above question.

Comment: Try removing all your CSS altogether. Does your content scroll then? If so, then add your CSS back in blocks and you'll be able to pinpoint the troublesome line(s)

Comment: I can give that a shot and see what happens. So weird this isn't working though. It's a pretty straight forward thing to implement in css.

Comment: yes, but CSS isn't the only thing that influences scrolling behavior -- JS can also meddle with scrolling.

Comment: What's odd is the damn thing is working everyone but IOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had a scroll lock on a component that was preventing it from working correctly. Sooo stupid haha.